# Bloquear push direto no branch master

Tags: github

Estou iniciando um projeto privado no Github e terá a participação de 5 desenvolvedores e eu serei o líder desse projeto. Cada desenvolvedor terá seu branch para publicar os arquivos para revisão. E eu ficarei responsável por validar antes de atualizar para o branch master. Para garantir que nenhum dos programadores suba as modificações direto no master gostaria de bloqueá-lo, para que não corra risco de atualizar no branch master uma versão com erros. Como faço para bloquear push direto no branch master?

Comment: Olha esses links do site do github.. Da para vc bloquear quem pode publicar diretamente na master. Nao sei se isso resolveria o seu problema
https://help.github.com/en/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions
ou 
https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-protected-branches

Comment: Este link pode te ajudar: https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-lock-no-branch-24979. Aproveite e de uma lida nesse tbm: https://willianjusten.com.br/trabalhando-com-git-hooks-de-forma-facil/

Comment: olha essa estratégia de cada dev ter uma branch me parece ruim... e ainda vai te dar trabalho na hora de fazer o merge de todas essas branches.... seria mais fácil usar uma única branch a partir de master que eles façam push pra lá, ou cada um criar um fork (mais recomendável) dessa branch, e só vc ter permissão de fazer o merge  para master

Comment: @RaquelAndrade, eu contratei o plano PRO do Github e não mostra a opção "Restrict who can push to this branch"

Comment: @RafaelChristófano no segundo link, logo no inicio, ele diz que Protected branches estao disponiveis para GITHub Pro
Talvez seja o caso de procurar na documentaçao do Github. Achei esse outro link tbm https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.15/admin/developer-workflow/configuring-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks